# What is the best way to authorize backend server to do read and writes to firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-iam

I have a backend server with a postgresql db. I need to write to my firestore database when one of the mutations is triggered.

my backend server will be dockerized and run on Google Cloud run.

Upon reading the docs, my initial plan is to use the env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to authorize my backend server. but on further reading on Google cloud run's docs, I came across this warning.

[image]
[SOURCE:](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#per-service-identity)

I'm wondering what is the usual/best approach in authorizing backend servers in these types of setups. Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Generally, all of the Google client libraries have an authentication mechanism where it checks for local credentials, but also accesses the google metadata service to get the service identity of the function or cloud run service.

So when you you the firebase admin library, it should use this same the same auth flow, so when deployed to cloud run, it will use the service account associated with that cloud run service.

That service account would then need the proper role, likely `datastore.user`. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam Let me know if you have questions

Comment: @Bajaco comment is good. The warning message is explicit. Maybe you can read the service identity page of Cloud Run to understand the mechanism. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity In any case, you rarely need a service account key file and to set this variable, locally, and never on Google Cloud.

Comment: @bajaco Thanks a lot for the reply!

If I understand you correctly, once I deploy my dockerized api server in cloudrun, and assign the service a service account with a role of say "editor" for my project, it would have permission to do read/write operations to my firestore, and I don't need to include credentials in my code like doing: 


import adminCreds from "src/adminCreds.json"

const adminApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(adminCreds),
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
})

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Wow, that sounds cool and makes authorization really easy, will test this out. thank you!

Comment: @bajaco: Thanks for helping! Can you post an answer below, so we get bring closure to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Google client libraries use an authentication mechanism where they either use the credentials file referenced in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, or make a request to the google metadata service to get the service identity of the calling resource.

So you should be able to set the appropriate permission on the service account associated with that cloud run service, such as `datastore.user`.

You can see the service account associated with the service on the cloud run page. I don't recall the default service account- but I would generally recommend to create a service account for each cloud run service to keep permissions as narrow and specific as possible.